# SystemVerilog loop unroll query

Tags: design, system-verilog, synthesis

I am trying to figure out the hardware generated for the SystemVerilog unrolled loop, where the same variable is assigned in a different iteration of the loop.

```
logic found;

always_comb
begin
    found = '0;
    gnt   = '0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    begin
        if(!found && req[i])
        begin
            found = '1;
            gnt[i] = '1;
        end
    end
end
```

I believe it generates a priority chain of internal "found" signals. It is also sticky in nature i.e. once set, it'll be set for all further iterations.

Question:
I am not able to find a section in the LRM which describes this feature. My concern is that this a tool optimisation by DC and not a language feature.

Please let me know if Verilog/SystemVerilog supports this as a language feature. Also, please share any literature on loop unrolling.

Comment: It is a priority arbiter with lowest index having the highest priority. `found` is just used internally to unroll. The signals `gnt` and `req` form the grant-request arbiter hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the functionality (I just wrote a hunt for one code to demo it). My main concern is, where is this behaviour i.e. found being a sticky bit which disables grant generation in further iteration is covered in LRM. 
Is this tool agnostic or does DC or genus  just implemented this as a feature.

Comment: This is just a use case of the language related to the behavior of Blocking Assignments inside a procedural block. LRM describes how Blocking Assignments behave, but it doesn't need to include all possible use cases.